# Sticky div, when refresh page and scroll up dont work as well

Tags: jquery

Here is my code:

```
if ($('.leed_blocks').length > 0) {
    var leedoffset = $('.leed_blocks').offset().top;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= leedoffset) {
        $('.leed_block').addClass('absolute');
        $('.leed_block').css('top', $(window).scrollTop() + 40);
    } else {
        $('.leed_block').removeClass('absolute');
    }
}
$(window).scroll(function() {
    // leed sticky
    if ($('.leed_blocks').length > 0) {
        if ($('.leed_blocks').is(':not(.absolute)'))
        // get the offset only if the sticky class is not added  
         leedoffset = $('.leed_blocks').offset().top - 60;
         if ($(window).scrollTop() > leedoffset) {
            $('.leed_blocks').addClass('absolute');
         $('.leed_blocks').css('top', $(window).scrollTop() + 40)
         } else {
         $('.leed_blocks').removeClass('absolute');
        }
    }
});
```

When I refresh the page and scroll up, blocks goes sticky but position is wrong and they scroll upper than we need, that because div has class absolute and we don't refresh offset when scroll.

### UPDATE

I have fotorama in the top of my website, and offset position when page start is different than real position we need. If i remove fotorama script work fine, but now its not. I just need method to scroll up and refresh offset like i do in code:

```
if ($('.leed_blocks').is(':not(.absolute)')) // get the offset only if the sticky class is not added leedoffset = $('.leed_blocks').offset().top - 60;
```

Comment: jsfiddle example work fine because that nor have fotorama, i can give you a link to my website.

Comment: Could be worth having a look at this answer - and the onload function. http://tinyurl.com/p4b7s2s